# How to convert LPTSTR to LPCTSTR&

Tags: c++

The function parameter is `LPCTSTR&`.

I have to pass `LPTSTR` variable as `LPCTSTR&`.

How to convert `LPTSTR` to `LPCTSTR&`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: LPTSTR data = _T("Hello");
 LPCTSTR const_data = static_cast<LPCTSTR>(data);

Comment: What function are you calling?

Comment: @Asesh `LPTSTR` does not have to be unicode, you should use `_T` macro

Comment: What problem do you have? Function accepting (reference to) const pointer should  have no problem accepting pointer...

Answer (score 3):

From my old C++ experience, you are trying to pass a pointer to a const string by reference. The compiler thinks you are going to change the pointer value. So you have 2 options

1. Make the parameter const so compiler can accept the LPSTR.
2. Or create a LPCTSTR pointer (an lvalue that can be changed) and pass it.

I have to tried to explain it in the following code snippet. I used VS 2017 + Windows 7 + SDK 10

```
void Foo(LPCTSTR &str)
{
    std::wcout << str;
    str = _T("World");
}

void FooConst(LPCTSTR const &str)
{
    std::wcout << str;
    //str = _T("World"); will give error
}

int main()
{
    LPTSTR str = new TCHAR[10];
    LPCTSTR str1 = str;
    lstrcpy(str, _T("Hello"));

//  Foo(str);// Error E0434 a reference of type "LPCTSTR &" (not const - qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "LPTSTR" HelloCpp2017
//  Foo(static_cast<LPCTSTR>(str));// Error(active) E0461   initial value of reference to non - const must be an lvalue HelloCpp2017    d : \jfk\samples\cpp\HelloCpp2017\HelloCpp2017\HelloCpp2017.cpp 19

    // Tell compiler you will not change the passed pointer
    FooConst(str);

    // Or provide a lvalue pointer that can be changed
    Foo(str1);

    std::wcout << str1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Asesh I wrote the code only to show the problem and solution with respect to this question. It is not complete.